# Flutter webview PayPal intergation error?

Tags: flutter, webview, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to integrate PayPal buttons like this:
https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

I put this sample code in a HTML file (`assets/paypal.html`), and read from assets into the WebView:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: WebView(
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller = webViewController;
          _loadHtml();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _loadHtml() async {
    String fileText = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/paypal.html');
    _controller!.loadUrl(Uri.dataFromString(fileText, mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8')).toString());
  }
```

But I get this error (**Uncaught Error: Bootstrap Error for buttons**):

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "insertPPTM [object Object]", source: https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD (2) [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap Error for buttons:

Can not read window host

Error: Can not read window host
    at j (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2:18528)
    at B (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2:18625)
    at zt (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2:58764)
    at Cu (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2:288789)
    at Object.__get__ (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2:288874)
    at o (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2:291801)
    at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2:291984
    at Module.<anonymous> (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2:292214)
    at t (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2:157)
    at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2:941", source: https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD (2) [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap Error for common:

Can not read window host

Error: Can not read window host
    at j (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2:18528)
    at B (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2:18625)
    at zt (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2:58764)
    at Iu (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2:289405)
    at Object.__get__ (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2:289453)
    at o (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2:291801)
    at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2:291984
    at Module.<anonymous> (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2:292214)
    at t (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2:157)
    at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2:941", source: https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD (2) [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "unhandled_error [object Object]", source: https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD (2) [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "unhandled_error [object Object]", source: https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD (2) [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Uncaught Error: Can not read window host", source: https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD (2) [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Uncaught Error: Can not read window host", source: https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD (2)
```

I tried 2 flutter WebView plugins, same error ( **webview_flutter 2.0.10** , **flutter_webview_plugin 0.4.0** )

Answer (score 1):

PayPal cannot be used from webviews, as the [documentation explains](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/info-security-guidelines/#secure-applications).

> Do not use a WebView to display PayPal web pages within your
> application
>
> Your application must not use a WebView or similar custom browser
> mechanism for display of PayPal web pages. Instead, use an appropriate
> PayPal SDK to manage the PayPal experience or launch the PayPal web
> page within the system browser or an approved browser-view mechanism
> such as Safari View Controller on iOS or Chrome Custom Tabs on
> Android.

If possible use a popup bridge to escape the webview:

- https://github.com/braintree/popup-bridge-ios
- https://github.com/braintree/popup-bridge-android

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this error because I realized that some cookies that I did not owe were being sent to paypal and a simple solution was this:

```js
const jsScript=`

 if(!window.location.hostname.includes('paypal'){
 
 //your code....
 
 }
`
```